# can't display images using CSS

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I started working on a wordpress website locally after downloading the wp-content folder from an existing website.

CSS styling is working alright but images (and fonts) are not displayed for some reason.
Both those things are assests fetched using `url()` in CSS but I don't understand why it happens. Obviously everything works the way it's supposed to on the live site.

images are in the theme folder:
`wp-content/themes/myTheme/assets/pageName/img.ext`

And through CSS I try to access them using:
 `background-image: url("/wp-content/themes/myTheme/assets/pageName/img.ext")`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your local setup, do you access WordPress directly at the root level of whatever hostname you are using - or do you have it in a folder below that? `/wp-content/...` with the leading slash refers to the domain root.

Comment: @CBroe okay that was just silly path issue, thank you for your message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was to extend the path by adding "/wordpress/" like so:
`background-image: url("/wordpress/wp-content/themes/myTheme/assets/pageName/img.ext")`